# How to change exercise numbers?

Tags: numbering

I am looking for simple code that simply makes me change the exercise numbers instead of the usual ordering "1, 2, 3, 4,....$

For example, I am doing a homework involving exercises 1, 5 and then 1, 2. I would like it to show

Exercise 1

Exercise 5

Exercise 1

Exercise 2

Instead of

Exercise 1

Exercise 2

...

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? How do you want to enter the numbers? What do you wish to gain over numbering the exercises manually?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using `exercise` package? If so, you can change the numbering manually by using `\setcounter` command. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
Something
\end{Exercise}

\setcounter{Exercise}{4}

\begin{Exercise}
something else
\end{Exercise}

\setcounter{Exercise}{0}

\begin{Exercise}
some other thing
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
and so on.
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

gives us:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Latex numbering is set to automatically increase the counter sequentially, unless you specifically tell it to. So, if you want numbers to occur out of sequential number, you will have to manually reset the counter yourself.

The [solution by Francis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131266/32509) is the way to do this by using the `exercise` package. Another way of achieving this is to manually define a command that does this for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{\noindent {\bf Exercise #1.}}
\begin{document}

\exercise{1} This is the first.

\exercise{3} This is the third.

\exercise{2} This is the second.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `exercises` package, you can change the numbering using the command:
`\setcounter{exercises@exercisenumber}{1}`. I have rewritten a previous example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercises} % exercises not exercise

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Something
\end{exercise}

% \setcounter{exercise}{4} % It gives an error
\setcounter{exercises@exercisenumber}{5} % It is right

\begin{exercise}
something else
\end{exercise}

%\setcounter{exercise}{0}
\setcounter{exercises@exercisenumber}{1}

\begin{exercise}
some other thing
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
and so on.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

And we obtain:

[image]

Comment: This answer has basically already been given by Francis.

Comment: With a different package, you're bound to have different things (like `exercise` *vs* `Exercise`, and a different counter).